# toggle class to HTML within an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, addclass, toggleclass

I'm developing a site where I want to toggle a class on the html element within an iframe on that page. I'm currently doing this

```
if ($('html').hasClass('flexbox')) {
  $('#flexbox').click(function () {
    $("html").toggleClass('flexbox').toggleClass('no-flexbox');
  });
}
```

which works on the documents HTML but I need to target the iframe id="myiframe" (for example)

```
if ($('#myiframe html').hasClass('flexbox')) {
  $('#flexbox').click(function () {
    $("#myiframe html").toggleClass('flexbox').toggleClass('no-flexbox');
  });
}
```

doesn't work. Any ideas using contentWindow or similar would be gratefully received.

update: the domain in the iframe will be different.

Comment: is the iframe in the same domain? if not, you simply cannot.

Comment: no it's not, and :o( that's that idea washed away. Onwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `contents()`.
try this

```
 if ($("#myiframe").contents().find("html").hasClass('flexbox')) {
   .....
```

note: make sure the iframe is in the same domain..

if it is in different domain then it is not possbile.. the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will restirct it to do so...

Comment: is it possible if it's a different domain completely?

Comment: no you can't... same origin policy .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript ...restrict it to do so..